# Как избавится от подвисаний анимации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, анимация

Задача: сделать в казино рулетку, которая будет выкидывать какой-то приз. По сути, это быстрая бесконечная карусель.

Дело в том, что в лисе она жестко подвисает на 500-1000мс из-за сборки мусора.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Может, есть готовые похожие плагины? Потому что мне ещё писать плавную остановку на нужном заранее выбранном элементе, что я ещё без понятия как вообще сделать, хотелось бы сэкономить время.

```js
var $carousel = $('#carousel');
var slideWidth = 500;
var prigress = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  prigress -= 50;
  $carousel.css({
    left: prigress
  });
  if (prigress % slideWidth == 0) {
    $('.slide:last').after($('.slide:first'));
    $carousel.css({
      left: 0
    });
    prigress = 0;
  }
}, 13);
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}

.window {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #222;
}

#carousel {
  width: 10000px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.slide {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="window">
    <div id="carousel">
      <span class="slide" id="b1">SLIDE-1</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b2">SLIDE-2</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b3">SLIDE-3</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b4">SLIDE-4</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b5">SLIDE-5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да нет, не подвисает. Все гладко.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Анимация гладкая, без задержек.

Comment: Автор пытается сделать аналог открытия кейсов CS:GO походу. Так почему не посмотреть на любом из подобных ресурсов как они это реализовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы изменяете набор значений для шести свойств CSS: margin, padding, top, left, bottom или right, браузер выполняет дополнительные вычисления того, как это отобразится на макете всей страницы.
Поэтому для увеличения производительности анимации лучше использовать:

```
.foo {
    transform: translate3d(x, y, z);
}
```

Причина, по которой transform является более производительным, заключается в том, что оно не затрагивают никакие другие элементы. Любые действия, которые вы выполняете, применяются только к одному элементу, и браузеру не нужно перестраивать все окно. Он модифицирует только ту часть экрана, которая содержит перемещающийся контент.

Так же при преобразовании элемента с помощью translate3d он обрабатывается через GPU в Webkit-браузерах, таких как Chrome и Safari (которые установлены на iPhone и iPad), в Internet Explorer 9/10, а также в последних версиях Firefox.

Поэтому при использовании `translate3d` вы получаете преимущества локальной перестройки экрана. Но кроме этого, вы получаете дополнительные преимущества, так как вся работа выполняется GPU.

Реализация примера через `transform`:

```js
var $carousel = $('#carousel');
var slideWidth = 500;
var prigress = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  prigress -= 50;
  $carousel.css("transform","translate3d("+prigress+"px,0,0)");
  if (prigress % slideWidth == 0) {
    $('.slide:last').after($('.slide:first'));
    $carousel.css({
      left: 0
    });
    prigress = 0;
  }
}, 13);
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}

.window {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #222;
}

#carousel {
  width: 10000px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.slide {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="window">
    <div id="carousel">
      <span class="slide" id="b1">SLIDE-1</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b2">SLIDE-2</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b3">SLIDE-3</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b4">SLIDE-4</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b5">SLIDE-5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```